# Denying permissions issue in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I've created a model Webuser based on the built in User model.

This is this model's ACL entry in "webuser.json":

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ]
```

To my surprise, I can login via POST /api/webusers/login with no problems. I expected all access to be denied.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I believe the [default user acls](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/v2.34.1/common/models/user.json#L37-L96) are still working and they are not overrided. The way loopback decides which ACL entry is effective for the request, is by selecting most specific one that appears later. So loopback has defined this entry:

```
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "login"
}
```

Since it's as specific as it gets, to beat that you have to add this in your model:

```
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY",
  "property": "login"
}
```

There's also another way to remove the default user acls via code but it's not documented.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I thought override and denying of full User access was enough. Your entry did the job.